# WSO2: Configuring xml multiple in a single project

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 6.5.0.

In the **WSO2HOME/conf/synapse.properties** I set property

```
synapse.commons.json.output.xmloutMultiplePI=true
```

for set the XML output to an xml-multiple processing instruction in XML to JSON transformations. (As [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+JSON+Message+Payloads) says )

This works fine, but In my WSO2 EI I have many Carbon Applications (CARs) and I need to apply this configuration only for a specific car, not to all because I have projects that stop working properly.

I know that all the properties set in synapse.properties will apply globally.

Is there a way to configure xml-multiple in a single project/sequence?